# Alpine email client does not sort alphabetically

Tags: email, sorting, alpine-mail

How can I get the [Alpine email client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_(email_client)) to correctly **`sort From`**? I am using Alpine v2.21 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server. When I attempt to do so for a folder by typing the '$' key and selecting 'F' for 'From', I typically get garbage like (I have redacted stuff using the `*` character):

```
      1 Thursday   Da***@******.***   (14K) RE: *************                   
      2 Friday     Fi***** ********** (44K) *****************
      3  7:31      Fi***** ********** (46K) *****************
      4 Wednesday  Re****, K***** *** (23K) *****************                  
      5 Thursday   Ra**** G****       (15K) RE: *************                   
  N   6 16:44      N**** R**** *      (71K) ***************** 
      7 Yesterday  F**** ************ (57K) *****************
      8 Wednesday  A**** S******      (85K) Re: *************       
  N   9 Friday     A*** O*****        (36K) *****************
  N  10 Thursday   a*****@***.***      (1M) *****************                 
  N  11 Thursday   a*****@***.***     (.1M) *****************                  
  N  12 Wednesday  A** J************* (.1M) *****************                           
  N  13 Thursday   A** J************* (.1M) *****************        
  A  14 Friday     S**** A*****       (27K) *****************
     15 Friday     S**** A*****       (26K) Re: *************
     16 Wednesday  A****** T********* (27K) *****************
```

Alpine appears to sort many subsets of my email messages in alphabetical order, but this is not sorting the entire folder alphabetically. For example, the email on the top line from `Da***@******.***` **should not** be at the top of the example list, etc.

**How do I get it to sort the entire folder uniformly in alphabetical order?**

Answers suggesting I use other email clients are out of bounds (I *do* use others, sometimes I have need of this specific client).

**Edit 1:** I am *not* asking about the default sort order for folders (e.g., as set through Settings > Confing > Sort Key).

Answer (score 1):

Order "From" uses the email address, not the real name (lines without @).

Comment: +1 Thank you, Polluks! Unfortunateyly, my question was apparently ambiguous: by "sort" I mean the sort function invoked when one has opened a mail folder and types the '$' key and alpine responds `Choose type of sort, or 'R' to reverse current sort :` with, e.g., S Subject, F From, etc. The sorting behavior I am describing in my question is about this behavior. I will make an edit now.